# Favorite External Enclosure?

Tags: hard-drive, external-harddrives

Hi All,

I've read the threads on external HDs but was wondering about everyone's opinions and enclosures/manufacturers that they liked.

Usually I just use the reviews on NewEgg for stuff like this, but I purchased a Vantec/Nexstar 3.5" USB 2.0 one a month or so back that was rated 5/5. It finally died a few days ago, and before that, it worked unreliably, flat-out not showing up on some systems, and registering fine on others. Not what I had in mind.

So, what do you rely on to keep your external hard drives protected and accessible?

Manufacturers and specific models are more important to me than transfer protocol/ports.

Thanks SSD!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use OWC Drives and or enclosures and they work great with Pro Tools. I have their 8 tb raid enclosure with 4 7200/2tb drives. Very much w2orth it. But not a movable drive. I also picked up a 3tb external work drive to transport work to home from OWC. Also a durable drive. But I work on a Mac FYI.

Comment: Thanks Robbie, checking them out now on the two recommendations from this thread.

Comment: Yet Another Plus One for OWC.

Answer (score 2):

Another vote for OWC. Fantastic products. I've had several of them over the years and they have been incredibly reliable. Using two of their quad interface mobile drives and one desktop drive at the moment and they're rock solid.

Great company with great customer service. Enough said.

Answer (score 1):

The OWC cases are my choice if the drive is "locked" in -i.e not needing to be swapped. For swap-able drives we've been using the Weibetech RTX cases in varying sizes (I use a 2 bay one in my main room and a single bay at my home suite).

I find it amusing that when I started at this studio I had a STACK of 4GB drives attached to my Mac, and now I regularly walk around with 4TB in my briefcase! :D

Comment: @sonsey those RTX cases are great.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just staying on your desk, I would use on of these:  http://www.newertech.com/products/hdddocks.php  I keep my drives in cases and got rid of a bunch of external enclosures this way. Less power supplys to worry about.

Michael
Rabbit Ears Audio
SFX: http://rabbitearsaudio.com
BLOG: http://sepulchra.com/blog/